# JAVA EE Servlets маппинг URI к методам

Tags: java, java-ee

Перехожу на Java EE c PHP, во всех фреймворках на PHP один контроллер может обрабатывать разные URI. Например для URL вида http://somesite.ru/controller/action фреймворк передаст управление методу action класса Controller. В Java EE контроллерами являются Servlets, но у него есть только doGet и doPost, т.е ими удобно обрабатывать всего один URI. Неужели Java не умеет маппить несколько URI к разным методам Servlet'а? И для каждого чиха, например по сути принадлижащих одному контролеру URI user/login, user/logout и.т.д мне плодить кучу сервлетов?

Comment: Это смотря как посмотреть во-первых. А во-вторых `servlet` никакой не контролёр, а самый низкий уровень обработки запросов. Если нужны контролёры, то используют такие фреймвёрки как `JSF` или `Spring`. Для `ReSTful` есть своя надстройка `JAX-RS`.

Comment: Хотя `JSF` - решение прямо из коробки, но он может оказать слишком отличным от прошлого опыта, и не всякий умеет его готовить. Не знаю как сейчас дела в `Spring`, но кажется он Вам больше понравится. Посмотрите, если его принципы покажутся знакомыми, то на JSF можно даже не терять время. Быть может благодаря ему (spring-у) и распространились повсюду эти контролёры.

Comment: @Sergey спасибо за ответ, в некоторых статьях сервлеты позиционировали именно как контролеры поэтому у меня закралась такая аналогия. Значит надо будет делать какой-то свой класс на подобие роутера запросов. Буду копать в сторону Spring.